# What is the meaning of the second value in the ESP8266 bootloader output?

Tags: esp8266

When connecting an esp8266 to a serial port at 74880 to flash or inspect it, depending on what pins are held down there are a series of diagnostic boot messages.

The line looks something like this:

```
rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)
```

The rst cause - the reset cause is very easy to find documentation on and has been useful in diagnosing low power or error conditions.

The first boot mode number is pretty well documented as being derived from `(gpio15 << 2 | gpio0 << 1| gpio 2)`, and the device will be expected to load code via the UART or from flash based on this value.

The second boot mode value, in this case 6 (I've seen 0, 1, 3 and 7 here), seems to be elusive and I've been unable to turn up documentation on what this diagnostic means. What should it do and where is there further documentation on it?

Comment: Espressif support engineer: "You just focus on 1st character. **Y is not a pricise judgement**." http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=8386#sthash.82ae9lvh.dpuf

Comment: Yes I found that - my thinking is it must mean something - otherwise why have it in the output? That it may be something SDIO related is the best lead I have yet.